# Which is the best resource to learn how to write a sitcom?

Tags: creative-writing, screenwriting, book, comedy

Can anyone suggest me the best resource to learn comedy screenwriting for Sitcoms? I have read Melvin Helitzer's "Comedy writing secrets" book and learnt a lot from it. But I want to know in depth about writing sitcoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like:

The Comedy Bible From Stand-up to Sitcom
The Comedy Writer's Ultimate "How To" Guide
by Judy Carter

More specific, less popular are:

1. The Eight Characters of Comedy: Guide to Sitcom Acting And Writing 2nd Edition
   by Scott Sedita
2. Elephant Bucks: An Inside Guide to Writing for TV Sitcoms
   by Sheldon Bull
3. Writing Television Sitcoms (revised)
   by Evan S. Smith